# Can the Samsung contact app be configured not to show suggestions when entering a new contact?

Tags: contacts, privacy

Can the Samsung contact app be configured not to show  suggestions when entering a new contact? The default behavior of showing suggestions is not ideal from a privacy standpoint when someone is around looking at whether one enters the proper information into the phone.

I use the latest Venmo app on Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.